# Add element to a varray data type

Tags: oracle, plsql

Let's say I have a table called `test_1`. One column of that table called `contact` which is a data type called `contact_data` and `contact_data` have a column called `personalarray`which is a varray of `personal` (another data type). My question is: How can I add elements to that varray called `personale`?

```
create or replace type personal as OBJECT(
        name varchar2(30),
        last_name varchar2(30),
        charge varchar2(50),
        mail varchar2(100)
    );

    create or replace type personalarray as varray(3) of personal;


    create or replace type contact_data as OBJECT(
        mail varchar2(40),
        fax varchar2(20),
        personale personalarray
    );

    create table test_1(
           id int,
           contact contact_data
        ); 
        /
```

I know how to insert for the first time, but how can I add elements to that varray? Here is how I can insert for the first time in that column:

```
update test_1 set contact = contact_data('mail','+5622',personalarray(personal('Ju','Cuneo','president','anothermail')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
create or replace type personal as OBJECT(
  name varchar2(30),
  last_name varchar2(30),
  charge varchar2(50),
  mail varchar2(100)
);
/

create or replace type personalarray as varray(3) of personal;
/


create or replace type contact_data as OBJECT(
  mail varchar2(40),
  fax varchar2(20),
  personale personalarray
);
/

create table test_1(
  id int,
  contact contact_data
); 
/

INSERT INTO test_1 (
  id,
  contact
) VALUES (
  1,
  contact_data(
    'mail',
    'fax',
    personalarray(
      personal( 'name1', 'lastname1', 'charge1', 'mail1' )
    )
  )
);
```

You can create a function to update the value:

```
CREATE FUNCTION updateContactDataPersonal(
  in_contact  IN test_1.contact%type,
  in_index    IN number,
  in_personal IN personal
) RETURN contact_data
IS
  p_contact contact_data := in_contact;
BEGIN
  IF ( p_contact IS NULL ) THEN
    p_contact := contact_data( NULL, NULL, personalarray() );
  END IF;
  IF ( p_contact.personale IS NULL ) THEN
    p_contact.personale := personalarray();
  END IF;
  IF ( in_index < 1 OR in_index > 3 ) THEN
    raise_application_error( -20001, 'Invalid index' );
  END IF;
  IF ( p_contact.personale.COUNT < in_index ) THEN
    p_contact.personale.extend( in_index - p_contact.personale.COUNT );
  END IF;
  p_contact.personale( in_index ) := in_personal;
  RETURN p_contact;
END;
/
```

**Update**:

```
UPDATE test_1
SET   contact = updateContactDataPersonal( contact, 3, personal( 'name3', 'lastname3', 'charge3', 'mail3' ) )
WHERE id      = 1;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT id,
       t.contact.mail,
       t.contact.fax,
       p.name,
       p.last_name,
       p.charge,
       p.mail
FROM   test_1 t
       CROSS JOIN
       TABLE( t.contact.personale ) p;
```

**Output**:

```
ID  CONTACT.MAIL    CONTACT.FAX NAME    LAST_NAME   CHARGE  MAIL
--  ------------    ----------- -----   ---------   ------- -----
1   mail            fax         name1   lastname1   charge1 mail1
1   mail            fax         -       -           -       - 
1   mail            fax         name3   lastname3   charge3 mail3
```